# Modified candy distribution task

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

There are N children standing in a line. Each child is assigned a rating value. 
You are giving candies to these children subjected to the following requirements:

- Each child must have at least one candy.
- Children with a higher rating get more candies **than anybody with lower**.

What is the minimum candies you must give?

Example:

Input:

[2, 1, 5]

Output:

6

**Complexity: O(n)**

There are already many solutions for this task when we notice only neighboring children (ex: https://leetcode.com/problems/candy/solution/) but what to do with this case?

Comment: So the lowest child gets 1 candy. The next lowest gets 2. Next lowest gets 3, etc. I think you'll find that the answer is `(n*(n-1))/2`, where `n` is the number of children.

Comment: @JimMischel, but it does not work for test example..
And ok, let's think that this formula is right - what if there are kids with the same rating? For ex [2, 2, 1 ,5]

Comment: @Sergy My mistake. It's `(n*(n+1))/2`. You didn't specify that there could be duplicate ratings. But that makes sense if the solution is O(n). Because the solution if they're unique is O(1).

Comment: I just looked at the solution there, and I don't understand what your question is. What case are you asking about that the posted solution doesn't handle?